# Returning a value from an iFrame in a popup to its parent window

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

Okay, ridiculously simple question, but it is doing my head in so any help would be appreciated!

I need to return a value to a form field, the value is returned in an iframe that is in a popup window.

So, I was thinking something along the lines of

```
window.top.parent.form.field.value = 'new value'
```

But that just gives me an error, any ideas would be really helpful! (not the greatest person in the world with javascript me)
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, and a few minutes after I posted that, I worked it out! Sorry guys! For reference here is the answer:

```
self.parent.opener.document.form.field.value = 'new value'
```